# can't start mongodb as sudo

Tags: mongodb

mongodb is returning errors related to access files when trying to start:

```
root@mongo01:~# sudo service mongodb start
mongodb start/running, process 4118
root@mongo01:~# Mon Jul 25 17:03:54 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4118 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit 
Mon Jul 25 17:03:54 [initandlisten] db version v1.8.2, pdfile version 4.5
Mon Jul 25 17:03:54 [initandlisten] git version: 433bbaa14aaba6860da15bd4de8edf600f56501b
Mon Jul 25 17:03:54 [initandlisten] build sys info: Linux bs-linux64.10gen.cc 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_41
Mon Jul 25 17:03:54 [initandlisten] couldn't open /var/lib/mongodb/adrise.ns errno:13 Permission denied
Mon Jul 25 17:03:54 [initandlisten] error couldn't open file /var/lib/mongodb/adrise.ns terminating
Mon Jul 25 17:03:54 dbexit: 
Mon Jul 25 17:03:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Mon Jul 25 17:03:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Mon Jul 25 17:03:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Mon Jul 25 17:03:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Mon Jul 25 17:03:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Mon Jul 25 17:03:54 closeAllFiles() finished
Mon Jul 25 17:03:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Mon Jul 25 17:03:54 dbexit: really exiting now
```

or

```
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4095 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit 
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 [initandlisten] db version v1.8.2, pdfile version 4.5
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 [initandlisten] git version: 433bbaa14aaba6860da15bd4de8edf600f56501b
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 [initandlisten] build sys info: Linux bs-linux64.10gen.cc 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_41
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 [initandlisten] info preallocateIsFaster couldn't run; returning false
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen std::exception: couldn't open file /var/lib/mongodb/journal/j._0 for writing errno:13 Permission denied, terminating
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 dbexit: 
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 closeAllFiles() finished
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 [initandlisten] shutdown: journalCleanup...
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Mon Jul 25 17:03:22 dbexit: really exiting now
```

when I try :

root@mongo01:~# mongodb -f /etc/mongodb.conf

it starts properly, any idea what it causing the issues?

Thanks

Comment: ubuntu 10.10 , installed as described at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? This suddenly started happening to me today and I can't figure it out. It's like it's not really running as sudo...

Comment: Try this answer written below http://stackoverflow.com/a/18013976/1202145

Answer (score 55):

> `Mon Jul 25 17:03:54 [initandlisten] couldn't open /var/lib/mongodb/adrise.ns errno:13 Permission denied`

It is a permissions issue, run the following command:

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you. Please accept this as the answer.

Comment: Worked perfectly. What I don't understand is why it worked before!

Answer (score 22):

So I had this problem rather suddenly, and I'm not sure why. The problem is that the upstart file wants to run mongo as the user mongodb. From `/etc/init/mongodb.conf`:

```
if [ "x$ENABLE_MONGODB" = "xyes" ]; then exec start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid mongodb --exec  /usr/bin/mongod -- --config /etc/mongodb.conf; fi
```

The chuid part tells it to run as a different user, even though you're running this script as root. For some reason, when I did `ls -l` in `/var/lib/mongodb`, I noticed that all the files were owned by root, which is why our mongodb user couldn't ge to them. I just did this:

```
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
```

And all was well. How did the issue happen in the first place? Not sure.

Comment: **Note:** you will probably need the recursive option `-R` from the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This file is your first data file `/var/lib/mongodb/adrise.ns`. Actually to be specific it's a namespace file that identifies other DB files.

For MongoDB to work, the `mongod` process will need access to two folders:

1. **Data folder**: in your case `/var/lib/mongodb/`
2. **Log folder**: not sure where you've put this

Now, if you run this as the root user, it should have access to every *every* folder. But you should ensure that no one else is locking this folder.

However, you should be able to run this with lower permissions. Typically you only need user-level permissions, just ensure that the user has access to those folder. If possible you'll want to run this at a level lower than root. Many people actually make a `mongodb` user and run it in its own context.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I remove mongo 3.6 and install mongo 2.4!
My solution:

1. Create new dir for you'r DB (some /var/lib/mongodb)
2. Edit config /etc/mongod.conf (dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb)
3. Start mongod

Answer (score 0):

Just try this command.

`sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb`

And

`sudo service mongod restart`

may help you.