# sudo service mongodb restart gives "unrecognized service error" in ubuntu 14.0.4

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I just installed mongoDB on ubuntu 14.0.4.
I tried to start the shell but I'm getting a connection refused error.

```
me@medev:/etc/init.d$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5
connecting to: test
2014-11-10T15:06:28.084-0500 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-11-10T15:06:28.085-0500 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

So I decided to try to restart the service but that's failing too.  I get the following error message:

```
me@medev:/etc/init.d$ sudo service mongodb restart
mongodb: unrecognized service
me@medev:/etc/init.d$
```

This is what I have in my /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log - http://pastebin.com/MrHt8tce

**what i've tried so far:**

I found another post here: [can't start mongodb as sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819852/cant-start-mongodb-as-sudo)
which made a comment about remove the mongo lock file.

I deleted the lock file and then retried my command but it still fails as you can see below:

```
me@medev:/var/lib/mongodb$ sudo rm mongod.lock 
me@medev:/var/lib/mongodb$ ls
journal  local.0  local.ns  _tmp

me@medev:/var/lib/mongodb$ sudo service mongodb start
mongodb: unrecognized service
```

But I can start it using /etc/init.d as you can see below:

```
me@medev:/var/lib/mongodb$ sudo /etc/init.d/mongod start
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mongod start

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mongod
mongod start/running, process 27469
me@medev:/var/lib/mongodb$ ls
journal  local.0  local.ns  mongod.lock

me@medev:/var/lib/mongodb$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5
connecting to: test
> db
test
>
```

Any ideas on why I can't start it using the service command would be appreciated.  From what I've read, i should be using sudo service mongodb

Comment: The problem is that the upstart scripts for mongodb are kind of broken when it comes down to _stopping_ mongod, as there are problems for identifying the PID correctly. I have noticed that problem, too and will submit a patch for it. Meanwhile, please restart your mongod instance with `sudo killall mongod && sleep 3 && sudo service mongod start`.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg you'd better add this as an answer to the question because this was the only thing which solved my problem! As of July of 2015 it doesn't seem to be fixed yet!

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and got it to work by following the instructions here - https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-mongodb-community-edition-on-ubuntu-linux/

This post says - "If you are using Ubuntu 16.04, you may run into an issue where you see the error mongodb: unrecognized service due to the switch from upstart to systemd."

Answer (score 46):

Try this:

Write `mongodb` instead of `mongod`

```
sudo service mongodb status
```

Comment: Weird - this worked for me as well even though the official documentation says to use 'mongod'.  Anybody know why?

Comment: Version or platform specific ? I installed mongodb 3.2.3 with the org package on an Ubuntu 14, and my service is indeed called `mongod`

Comment: You man need:
`$ sudo mongod --repair --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/`

Comment: Mongo really needs to clean up their documentation etc if they are to compete.

Answer (score 20):

I got the same error one day You should use this:

1.Get the status of your mongo service:

```
 /etc/init.d/mongod status
```

or

```
 sudo service mongod status
```

2.If it's not started repair it like this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
mongod --repair
sudo service mongodb start
```

And  check again if the service is started again(1)

Comment: Non of those works 
It says `bash: /etc/init.d/mongod: No such file or directory` 
or `Unrecognised Service`

Comment: on my server it's called mongodb instead of mongod for some reason.

Comment: If you don't have a file in /etc/init.d/mongod (or /etc/init.d/mbongod, then you need to create one. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22336712/249672

Answer (score 8):

For me the solution was to replace

```
service mongod start
```

with

```
start mongod
```

Comment: This option worked for me in MongoDB 4. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure the file (ex. /etc/init.d/mongodb) has execute permissions.

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/mongodb
```

Comment: I get "No such file or directory". Which Ubuntu version are you running?

Answer (score 3):

For debian, from the 10gen repo, between 2.4.x and 2.6.x, they renamed the init script /etc/init.d/mongodb to /etc/init.d/mongod, and the default config file from /etc/mongodb.conf to /etc/mongod.conf, and the PID and lock files from "mongodb" to "mongod" too. This made upgrading a pain, and I don't see it mentioned in their docs anywhere. Anyway, the solution is to remove the old "mongodb" versions:

```
update-rc.d -f mongodb remove
rm /etc/init.d/mongodb
rm /var/run/mongodb.pid
diff -ur /etc/mongodb.conf /etc/mongod.conf
```

Now, look and see what config changes you need to keep, and put them in mongod.conf.

Then:

```
rm /etc/mongodb.conf
```

Now you can:

```
service mongod restart
```

Answer (score 3):

I installed mongo server on Debian Jessie using [manual from official site](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/#install-community-debian-pkg).

It didn't started after recommended command  `sudo service mongod restart` with the same `error - mongodb: unrecognized service`.

After looking into installed package contents, I noticed that it contains only Systemd service unit, but no SystemV init script:

```
# dpkg -L mongodb-org-server
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/mongod
/usr/share
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/mongodb-org-server
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server
/usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/LICENSE-Community.txt
/usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/README
/usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/copyright
/usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/GNU-AGPL-3.0.gz
/usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES.gz
/usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/MPL-2.gz
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/mongod.1.gz
/etc
/etc/mongod.conf
/lib
/lib/systemd
/lib/systemd/system
/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service
```

But my system was running on SysV init:

```
# stat /proc/1/exe
File: '/proc/1/exe' -> '/sbin/init'
```

So, there are 2 options now:

- (Continue on SysV) [Write sysV init script manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336075/linux-process-into-a-service/22336712#22336712) as @khylo mentioned above
- ([Switch to SystemD](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd#Installing_and_Testing)) and run `systemctl start mongod`

Answer (score 2):

For me nothing have helped, I've ended up with a solution:

create `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` file with content

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then start/stop commands should work

```
$ sudo service mongod start
```

For reference - I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, MongoDB 3.2.9 installed from

```
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Ubuntu in WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), you will have issues because WSL does not currently support systemd.

The link below explains how to run MongoDB without systemd, and even how to add a script for using the service command with WSL.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-database#mongodb-init-system-differences

> tutorials may start MongoDB using the operating system's built-in init system. You might see the command sudo systemctl status mongodb used in tutorials or articles. Currently WSL does not have support for systemd (a service management system in Linux).
>
> You shouldn't notice a difference, but if a tutorial recommends using sudo systemctl, instead use: sudo /etc/init.d/. For example, sudo systemctl status docker, for WSL would be sudo /etc/init.d/docker status ...or you can also use sudo service docker status.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have installed the version of mongodb for the wrong system distro.

Take a look at how to install mongodb for ubuntu and debian:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

I had a similar problem, and what happened was that I was installing the ubuntu packages in debian

Answer (score 0):

Original Source - https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-mongodb-community-edition-on-ubuntu-linux/

---

If you're on Ubuntu 16.04 and face the unrecognized service error, these instructions will fix it for you:-

1. Open a terminal window.
2. Issue the command `sudo apt-key adv —keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 —recv EA312927`
3. Issue the command `sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org.list`
4. Issue the command `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org.list`
5. Copy and paste one of the following lines from below (depending upon your release) into the open file.
   For 12.04: `deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu precise/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse`
   For 14.04: `deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse`
   For 16.04: `deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse`

Make sure to edit the version number with the appropriate latest version and save the file.

**Installation**
Open a terminal window and issue command `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`

Let the installation complete.

**Running MongoDB** To start the database, issue the command `sudo service mongodb start`. You should now be able to issue the command to see that MongoDB is running: `systemctl status mongodb`

**Ubuntu 16.04 solution**
If you are using Ubuntu 16.04, you may run into an issue where you see the error mongodb: unrecognized service due to the switch from upstart to systemd. To get around this, you have to follow these steps.

- If you added the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org.list`, remove it with the command `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org.list`
- Update apt with the command `sudo apt-get update`
- Install the official MongoDB version from the standard repositories with the command `sudo apt-get install mongodb` in order to get the service set up properly
- Remove what you just installed with the command `sudo apt-get remove mongodb && sudo apt-get autoremove`

Now follow steps 1 through 5 listed above to install MongoDB; this should re-install the latest version of MongoDB with the systemd services already in place. When you issue the command `systemctl status mongodb` you should see that the server is active.

---

I mostly copy pasted the above (with minor modifications and typo fixes) from here - https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-mongodb-community-edition-on-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution that worked for me with the same problem (I think):

`mv /var/lib/mongodb /var/lib/mongodb_backup
mkdir /var/lib/mongodb
chmod 700 /var/lib/mongodb
chown mongodb:daemon /var/lib/mongodb
systemctl restart mongodb or service mongod restart`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mongod` command instead of `mongodb`, if you find any issue regarding dbpath in mongo you can use my answer in the link below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53057695/8247133